# RSpec2: stub a method called by another method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, stub

I've a problem with rspec2 and rails 3. A stubbed method is called only if I call it directly, not if it's called by a method of the same class.

This is my model:

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  def choose_a_winner_for_attack (p_attack)
     puts "REAL choose_a_winner_for_attack"
    (rand() < p_attack)
  end

  def attacks(attacked_place, attack_deployments)
    ….
    win = choose_a_winner_for_attack(p_attack)
    ….
  end
end
```

In the spec, after Creating a new place, I stub it:

```
place.stub!(:choose_a_winner_for_attack).and_return(true)
```

and then I call:

```
place.choose_a_winner_for_attack 0
```

it return always true end I never see the log  "REAL choose_a_winner_for_attack".

But if I call:

```
place.attacks(…)
```

it call the real method "choose_a_winner_for_attack" (I see the log "REAL choose_a_winner_for_attack").

**UPDATE**
This the code of the spec:

```
  #Stub Place
  place = @user0.place
  place.stub!(:choose_a_winner_for_attack).and_return(true)
  puts "INSIDE SPEC #{f.object_id} #{f.choose_a_winner_for_attack 0}"
  place.attacks(other_place, deployments)
```

Here there is the problem, I was expecting the stubbed method is called.

Comment: Since you are not showing real code, are you sure that the object with the stub, is the same that receives the `attacks` method?

Comment: I'm printing "place.object_id" and "object_id" inside the choose_a_winner_for_attack, they are the same.

Comment: Can you post the code for your spec?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it works:

```
class A
  def foo
    "foo"
  end

  def bar
    foo
  end
end

describe A do
  it "stubs methods called from within other methods" do
    a = A.new
    a.stub(:foo).and_return("baz")
    a.foo.should == "baz" # passes
    a.bar.should == "baz" # passes
  end
end
```

Comment: I've tried to method foo and bar to my code and a spec very similar to yours. It works if I get an instance of place with Place.new, it doesn't if I get it from @user0.place .... I don't understand why...

Comment: With a factory. @user0.place is a Place I've checked and it's not nil. @user0.place is an has_one association.

Comment: Seems like it ought to work. Must be something else that we can't see. If you could post the spec file and the factory definitions it might help. Maybe do it as a gist if it's too much code to go here.